# How to edit Zend form with edit button next to each field

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have file (ProfileController.php) which contains the following code:

```
public function editAction() {

        if (Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()) {
        try {
            $form = new Application_Form_NewStory();
            $request = $this->getRequest();
            $story = new Application_Model_DbTable_Story();
            $result = $story->find($request->getParam('id'));

           // $values = array(
           //     'names' => $result->names,
           //     'password' => $result->password,
           // );

            if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
                if ($form->isValid($request->getPost())) {
                    $data = array(
                        'names' => $form->getValue("names"),
                        'password' => $form->getValue("password"),
                    );
                    $form->populate($data->toArray());
                    $where = array(
                        'id' => $request->getParam('id'),
                    );
                    $story->update($data, $where);
                }
            }
            $this->view->form = $form;
            $this->view->titleS= $result->title;
            $this->view->storyS= $result->story;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e;
        }
    } else {
        $this->_helper->redirector->goToRoute(array(
            'controller' => 'auth',
            'action' => 'index'
        ));
    }

    }
```

and another file (edit.phtml) with following code:

```
    <?php
        try
            {
                 $tmp = $this->form->setAction($this->url());

         //$tmp->titleS=$this->title;
         //$tmp->storyS=$this->story;

          //echo $tmp->title = "aaaaa";
            }
          catch(Exception $e)
            {
                 echo $e;
            }

    ?>
```

I would like the users to be able to edit their Username and password. How do I go about it?

Comment: Check this tutorial by [Rob Allen](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial-18/)

Answer (score 0):

First: move the Zend_Auth stuff up to init() or preDispatch(), that way Auth will run against any or all actions in the controller.

The trick in getting more then one submit button to work is to give the buttons different names so that getParam('') has something to work with.

Normally I only do this sort of thing when doing deletes, for edit's or update's I just submit the whole array back to the database. I typically use the `Zend_Db_Table_Row save()` method instead of `Zend_Db_Table's` `insert()` or `update()` so the mechanism is a little different.

I just use a simple form to perform an update, here is the controller code (the view just echo's the form):

```
//update album information
public function updatealbumAction()
    {   //get page number from session
        $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('page');
        //get album id
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

        $model = new Music_Model_Mapper_Album();
        //fetch the album database record
        $album = $model->findById($id);

        $form = new Admin_Form_Album();
        //this form is used elsewhere so set the form action to this action
        $form->setAction('/admin/music/updatealbum/');

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) {
                $data = $form->getValues();//get valid and filtered form values

                $newAlbum = new Music_Model_Album($data);//create new entity object

                $update = $model->saveAlbum($newAlbum);//save/update album info

                $this->message->addMessage("Update of Album '$update->name' complete!");//generate flash message
                $this->getHelper('Redirector')->gotoSimple('update', null, null, array('page' => $session->page));//redirect back to the page the request came from
            }
        } else {
            $form->populate($album->toArray());
            $this->view->form = $form;
        }
    }
```

This is a pretty common update action.

Now here is how you might use different request parameters to perform an action on a record. I use this to delete database records but anything is possible.

```
public function deleteAction()
    {
        $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('page');
        $request = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        try {
            switch ($request) {
                //if 
                case isset($request['trackId']):
                    $id = $request['trackId'];
                    $model = new Music_Model_Mapper_Track();
                    $model->deleteTrack($id);
                    $this->message->addMessage("Track Deleted!");

                    break;
                case isset($request['albumId']):
                    $id = $request['albumId'];
                    $model = new Music_Model_Mapper_Album();
                    $model->deletealbum($id);
                    $this->message->addMessage("Album Deleted!");

                    break;
                case isset($request['artistId']):
                    $id = $request['artistId'];
                    $model = new Music_Model_Mapper_Artist();
                    $model->deleteArtist($id);
                    $this->message->addMessage("Artist Deleted!");

                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            $this->getHelper('Redirector')->gotoSimple('update', null, null, array('page' => $session->page));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->message->addMessage($e->getMessage());
            $this->getHelper('Redirector')->gotoSimple('update', null, null, array('page' => $session->page));
        }
    }
```

you can pass the request parameters as submit button labels or as urls or whatever works for you.

Good Luck!